# After change a link and title of subsite search box of list don't work

Tags: search, search-results

I must change a name and link of the subsite. After this change all list on this subsite stoped work search box of the list.

After I search on whole Site Collection it show me element on this subsite, but after I go to this subsite where I must change a name and a link, the search box nothing shown:

[image]

Please help me. I don't know how to fix this. I tried reindex all the hist and run Full claw but it not help.

Comment: If I choose in all Site Collection in 3 web page it work, but in vebpart it doesen't work. Please help.

Comment: What exactly did you change? Take me through the steps you took.

Comment: Only the name of a site, and the link to the site, but now i know why. I used Polish sign "ż" in the name of link site, and after this change the searching box again run.

Answer (score 0):

I know now why it don't work searching box in the list. The link for subsite have got polish sign "ż", and that why it can't searching in all list wchich wer in subsite. After I change "ż" to "z" it worked again when I run Full Crawli :)

Comment: Awesome! Mark this as your answer.